# How can I merge two arrays from Axios into one "datasource" array and pass it as a data into syncfusion SeriesDirective component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, syncfusion

the main problem is that when I console.log "datasource" array it first shows that array populated the way I want to, which is:

```
[
0:{ date: date, value: value },
1:{ date: date, value: value },
...
]
```

but then after the first log loads it suddenly changes to a empty array [];

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { ChartComponent, LineSeries, ColumnSeries, SeriesDirective, SeriesCollectionDirective, Inject } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts'
import axios from 'axios'

const StablesTVLchart = () => {

  const [stables, setStables] = useState([])
  
  const dates = new Array;
  const totalCirculating = new Array;
  const totalPegged = new Array;
  const datasource = new Array;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://stablecoins.llama.fi/stablecoincharts/all?stablecoin=1')
      .then(res => {
        
        setStables(res.data)
        
        // Populate dates array and totalCirculating array /
        for (var i = 0; i < stables.length; i++){
          dates.push(parseFloat(stables[i].date))
          totalCirculating.push(data[i].totalCirculatingUSD)
        }
        
         // Populate totalPegged array /
        for (var y = 0; y < totalCirculating.length; y++){
          totalPegged.push(totalCirculating[y].peggedUSD)
        }
        
         // Populate datasource array with date and totalPegged /
        for (var e = 0; e < datadate.length; e++){
          datasource.push({ date: dates[e], value: totalPegged[e] })
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, []);

  console.log(datasource);

  const primaryxAxis = {visible: false }
  const primaryyAxis = { labelFormat: '${value}K', visible: false }
  const palette = ["skyblue"]
  
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
    <ChartComponent id="charts" primaryXAxis={primaryxAxis} primaryYAxis={primaryyAxis} palettes=       {palette}>

      <Inject services={[ColumnSeries, LineSeries]} />
      
      <SeriesCollectionDirective>
        <SeriesDirective dataSource={datasource} xName='date' yName='value' name='TVL'/>
      </SeriesCollectionDirective>
      
      </ChartComponent>
    </div>
  )
}

export default StablesTVLchart
```

I recon that its possible I need to somehow make this datasource array into a state array?

If anyone has any clues or an idea on how to do this, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears from the code you provided that you are using state to store the data, but immediately trying to use it, I will remind you that React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

Also for improvement of the code readability, you can use something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://stablecoins.llama.fi/stablecoincharts/all?stablecoin=1')
    .then(res => {
      const stables = res.data;
      const dates = stables.map(item => parseFloat(item.date));
      const totalCirculating = stables.map(item => item.totalCirculatingUSD);
      const totalPegged = totalCirculating.map(item => item.peggedUSD);
      const datasource = totalPegged.map((value, index) => ({ date: dates[index], value }));
      setStables(datasource);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The api returns a single array. You store the api's response in a state you don't use. You then store parts of the data of original response in 4 arrays by mutating them (using `push`). You try to use one of the mutated arrays (`datasource`) in the view, but as soon as the view is re-rendered (because of `setStables(res.data)`) the array is re-created with an empty array. In addition, updating a variable/constant asynchronously, and mutating the arrays doesn't cause a re-render, and even if it would react won't detect the change, and won't change the view.

Solution:

1. Use `Array.map()` to create a new array based on the api's response array
2. Store result of the map into the state, and use that state in your view

Example:

```
const StablesTVLchart = () => {
  const [datasource, setDatasource] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://stablecoins.llama.fi/stablecoincharts/all?stablecoin=1')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setDatasource(data.map(({ date, totalCirculatingUSD }) => ({
          date: parseFloat(date),
          value: totalCirculatingUSD.peggedUSD
        })))
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, []);

  console.log(datasource);
}
```